# Проблема с показом текста при нажатии кнопок

Tags: javascript, css

```html
 <div class="question">
     <p class="question__text"></p>
     <button class="question__btn"></button>
 </div>
     <p class="answer__text"></p>
```

Мне нужно чтобы при нажатии кнопок появлялся текст с ответом для каждой. У меня при нажатии любой из кнопок открывается только текст первой. Как исправить это?

```css
   .answer__text {
      display: none;
    }
```

```js
const questionBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".question__btn")

questionBtn.forEach((element => {
  element.addEventListener("click", () => {
    element.classList.toggle("question__btn--active")
    document.querySelector(".answer__text").style.display = "block"


  });
}))
```

Comment: `document.querySelector(".answer__text").style.display = "block"` находит первый элемент считая с документа, вот и находит каждый раз один и тот же. Если например этот текст у вас в каждой кнопке используйте `element.querySelector(".answer__text").style.display = "block"`

Comment: Или как у вас там устроено

Comment: А вообще на заметку: есть такой прекрасный аттрибут - `hidden`.  Хотите скрыть элемент - `element.hidden = true;` хотите показать `element.hidden = false;` и не надо `style` лишний раз трогать

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло. Теперь вообще не открывается текст при нажатии.

Comment: Покажите вашу html конструкцию

Comment: Добавил. В вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

## Конструкция

По описанию вам нужно генерировать для каждого вопроса отдельный блок, со своим вопросом, ответом и кнопкой который откроет этот ответ. Мне кажется вам надо такая конструкция:

```html
<body>
  <template id="question-block">
    <div class="question">
      <p class="question__text"></p>
      <button class="question__btn"></button>
    </div>
    <p class="answer__text" hidden></p>
  </template>
</body>
```

## Решение

```js
function generateQuestionBlock(question, answer) {
  const templateQuestionBlock = document.querySelector(`template#question-block`);
  const divQuestionCloneFragment = templateQuestionBlock.content.cloneNode(true);
  divQuestionCloneFragment.querySelector(`p.question__text`).innerText = question;

  const divAnswerText = divQuestionCloneFragment.querySelector(`p.answer__text`);
  divQuestionCloneFragment.querySelector(`button.question__btn`).addEventListener(`click`, (event) => {
    divAnswerText.hidden = false;
  });
  divAnswerText.innerText = answer;
  document.body.appendChild(divQuestionCloneFragment);
}

generateQuestionBlock(`Как вам мой ответ?`, `Ясно`);
generateQuestionBlock(`У вас оствлтсь вопросы?`, `Надеюсь что нет`);
```

```html
<body>
  <template id="question-block">
    <div class="question">
      <p class="question__text"></p>
      <button class="question__btn">Показать ответ</button>
    </div>
    <p class="answer__text" hidden></p>
  </template>
</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Просто у меня уже готовы блоки и их не нужно клонировать и создавать такую сложную конструкцию. Мне нужно просто чтобы при нажатии любой из кнопок открывался скрытый текст. Почему-то когда document.querySelector меняешь на element.querySelector перестает работать работать код.

Comment: @user512592 `element` - это кнопка. Так будет работать, если у вас ответы в кнопках. Попробуйте вместо `element.hidden = false` это - `element.closest('p.answer__text').hidden = false`