# Проблема с показом текста при нажатии кнопок

Tags: javascript

Почему текст при нажатии кнопок не показывается?

```js
const questionBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".question__btn")

questionBtn.forEach((element => {
  element.addEventListener("click", () => {
    element.classList.toggle("question__btn--active")
    element.querySelector(".answer__text").style.display = "block"
  });
}))
```

```css
.answer__text {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
 <div class="question">
     <p class="question__text">Кто ты?</p>
     <button class="question__btn">button</button>
 </div>
     <p class="answer__text">Who are you?</p>
```

Comment: Возможно дубликат вопроса: [Проблема с показом текста при нажатии кнопок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1453763/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba)

Comment: Судя по предыдущему вопросу `answer__text` лежит не внутри `question__btn`, потому вот здесь `element.querySelector(".answer__text")` элемент и не находит.

Comment: во первых лучше использовать `делегирование событий` вместо порождения множества `слушателей` во-вторых ответ не возможно дать пока Вы не добавите в вопрос Вашу разметку.

Comment: Добавил разметку

Comment: @user512592 как я и писал, так как `answer__text` не находится внутри элемента `question__btn` вот это `element.querySelector(".answer__text").style.display = "block"` работать не будет, так как Вы ищете элемент с классом `answer__text` внутри `question__btn`.

Comment: @user512592 Вам лучше удалить один из дублей вопроса, напишите тут какой хотите удалить, так как вопрос с ответом нельзя удалить самостоятельно. Лучше удалить этот, тут только мой ответ, со мной проще договориться)

Comment: Предыдущий. Спасибо за ответ, все заработало.

Comment: @user512592 Пометьте галочкой мой ответ который подошел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как в вопрос добавилась разметка, я решил дополнить свой ответ.

**Обновление**

В данном случае вам не нужен поиск, достаточно подняться до родителя и найти его следующего соседа, это и будет параграф. Так же я изменил немного логику, теперь текст можно не только показать но и скрыть.
Думаю остальное Вы доработаете сами как сочтете нужным.

```js
const questionBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".question__btn")

questionBtn.forEach((element => {
  element.addEventListener("click", () => {
    element.classList.toggle("question__btn--active")
    const p = element.parentNode.nextElementSibling
    const isBlock = p.style.display === "block"
    p.style.display = isBlock ? "none" : "block" 
  });
}))
```

```css
.answer__text {
  display:none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.question__btn--active{
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="question">
   <p class="question__text">Кто ты?</p>
   <button class="question__btn">button</button>
</div>
   <p class="answer__text">Who are you?</p>
   
<div class="question">
   <p class="question__text">Как тебя зовут?</p>
   <button class="question__btn">button</button>
</div>
   <p class="answer__text">What is you name?</p>
```

**Предыдущий ответ**

Представим что мы хотим написать программу для изучения английского, кнопки это карточки с текстом который нужно перевести. При нажатию на кнопку покажется еще и перевод.

*Конечно без разметки в вопросе сложно догадаться как она выглядит у Вас, но это пол дела, нужно еще понимать что Вы собираетесь добиться, потому что даже приведенный вопросе код работает но возможно не так как Вы ожидали.*

```js
    const questionBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".question__btn")
    questionBtn.forEach((element => {
      element.addEventListener("click", () => {
        element.classList.toggle("question__btn--active")
        element.querySelector(".answer__text").style.display = "block"
      });
    }))
```

```css
.answer__text{  display: none; font-weight: bold;}
.question__btn{ background: white; }
.question__btn--active{ background: lightgreen; }
```

```html
   <button class="question__btn">
      <p>Я знаю это</p>
      <p class="answer__text">I know it</p>
   </button>
   <button class="question__btn">
      <p>Я люблю читать книги</p>
      <p class="answer__text">I like read books</p>
   </button>
   <button class="question__btn">
      <p>А что любишь ты?</p>
      <p class="answer__text">What do you like?</p>
   </button>
```